# Canvas Draw To is not drawing line

Tags: javascript, html

I have built a function in javascript to draw to and from set points on the canvas. All of my points work correctly expect c. If I try to draw a line from any point to c it does not work.

Javascript

```
var a = {x:0, y:0};
var b = {x:350, y:0};
var c = {x:0, y:350};
var d = {x:350, y:350};
var e = {x:100, y:100};
var f = {x:100, y:250};
var g = {x:250, y:250};
var h = {x:250, y:100};

function drawLine(a, b)
{
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(a.x,a.y);
ctx.lineTo(b.x,b.y);
ctx.stroke();
}
drawLine(d, c);
```

Why do all points work expect c????

Comment: Maybe it does work, but you just can't see it because it's right on he edge of the `<canvas>`.

Comment: I've tried it will all points. And none work. The d point was just an example. I've tried to f, a, h

Comment: [It works for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/g2j9u9L2/)

Comment: Mmm... Must be one of those error you need to sleep on :S. Its not working at all.

Comment: I'd ad a `console.log("a: ", a, "b: ", b)` to makes sure that "c" contains what it should.

Comment: I'd like to see how your canvas is set up. What are the dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this, I am guessing the width and the height of the canvas is 350.

Assuming that, they are working. Its just being drawn on the border. You're trying to go from `{x:0, y:350}` to `{x:350, y:350}`. Notice how the `y` for both is `350`. This means it will draw from the `bottom,left` corner to the `bottom,right` corner, exactly staying at `y : 350`, which is the border. So therefore you will not be able to see it.

Try changing `var c = {x:0, y:350};` to `var c = {x:0+5, y:350-5};`, leaving it at `{x:5, y:345}`. And you will notice that for point `c` the lines now show, but very very close to the border.